# Run element text property is not set after navigating back from another frame

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

I am trying to set the text property of Run element based on number of records fetched from a service in dot net, the values are set properly when I am initially on the main page but when I navigate to another page and come back to the main page the property shows the value is set (using add/quick watch) but it does not show up on the UI.
below is the code for the same

```
if (lstTabIndex != 0) 
{
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(msgCount.Text))
       totalMessages = query.Count();
  else
       totalMessages = query.Count() + Convert.ToInt32(msgCount.Text);

       msgCount.Text = Convert.ToString(totalMessages);
 }
```

and below is the xaml code

```
 <ListView x:Name="lstTabs" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListViewItemStyle}" IsActiveView="True" Background="#FFC0A789" BorderBrush="Blue" SelectionChanged="lstTabls_SelectionChange" FontSize="25" SelectionMode="Single" Margin="0,0,0,0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <TextBlock x:Name="tabMessage" TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="25" Grid.Column="0" Width="Auto" Height="34" >
                Message
                <Run x:Name="msgCount" Foreground="Red" FontWeight="ExtraBold"></Run>
            </TextBlock>
            <TextBlock x:Name="tabTimeTracker" TextAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1" Width="Auto" FontSize="25" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" >
                TimeTracker
            </TextBlock>
        </ListView>
```

Any help on this will be grateful.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't understand the rationale of putting a Run inside a Listview.
You can very well put it outside as well and then try doing what you are

Comment: I have made the styling of the list view to look like a tab control and I want to show the count of messages received as a notification when user is on another tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got a somewhat roundabout solution for this.

I have added and removed a run element dynamically in the OnNavigatedTo overridden function and it works just the way I want it to. Don't know why the normal way didn't work though.
Below is the code for the same

```
 TextBlock txtBlockObject = (TextBlock)lstTabs.FindName("tabMessage");
 txtBlockObject.Inlines.Remove(runElementObj);
 runElementObj = null;
 // Create a new instance of run element and add it to the text block
 runElementObj = new Run();
 runElementObj.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Red);
 runElementObj.FontWeight = FontWeights.ExtraBold;
 txtBlockObject.Inlines.Add(runElementObj);
```